# How to Change the items of a ComboBox when a value of another is changed?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I m doing a small project which manipulates a Albums of a singer, so the project provides you to add new singer to add album for specific singer and to add songs to  specific album for specific singer , i m trying to get the user the chance to get the singer albums so he doesn't have to type it with his hand so I used two `ComboBox` one named "AvailableSinger" which clearly for available singer and the other "AlbumAvailable" for available albums for each singer, when the user select a singer the "AlbumAvailable" will display the albums of a singer selected in "AvailableSinger"

I've added two artists "Adele" and "Eminem" but when I choose Eminem the "Hello" album of "Adele" will only display.

```
package sample;

import MusicManiPulation.Album;
import MusicManiPulation.Singer;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddSongsToAlbum {

@FXML
ComboBox<String> AvailableSinger ;
@FXML
ComboBox<Album> AlbumAvailble ;

public void initialize(){
    AvailableSinger.getItems().addAll(Singer.getInstance().GetSingerNames());
    AvailableSinger.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    ArrayList<Album> AlbumList =Singer.getInstance().getAlbumNameoforSinger(AvailableSinger.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    AlbumAvailble.getItems().addAll(AlbumList);

}


}
```

The Singer Class(in case you want to understand what I am doing)

```
package MusicManiPulation;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Singer {

   public static Singer Instance = new Singer();

    Map<String , ArrayList<Album>>AlbumListfoEachSinger ;

    private Singer() {
        this.AlbumListfoEachSinger = new HashMap<>();
    }

  public ArrayList<String> GetSingerNames(){
        ArrayList<String>SingerName = new ArrayList<>();
        SingerName.addAll(AlbumListfoEachSinger.keySet());
        return SingerName;
  }


    public Map<String, ArrayList<Album>> getAlbumListfoEachSinger() {
        return AlbumListfoEachSinger;
    }


    public ArrayList<Album> getAlbumNameoforSinger(String SingerName){
        return AlbumListfoEachSinger.get(SingerName);
    }

    public static Singer getInstance() {
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

[image: Adele Album Displaying Picture]

[image: When Selecting Eminem]

As you can see only the Adele albums display but when selecting another Artist it doesn't work.

Comment: Add a `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener` to the `value` property of the `ComboBox` and change the items of the other `ComboBox` as appropriate.

Comment: it seems easy xD but i didn't know how to well-override it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to pay more attention to naming conventions in Java. Check this [resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

You can solve your problem by using **one of the following methods**:

- **Listeners**:

Listeners can be added to JavaFX properties, you can add a listener that will fill the albums for a specific singer when a new singer is selected. Add this listener in your initialize method:

```java
availableSingers.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldSelectedSinger, newSelectedSinger) -> {
    List<Album> albums = Singer.getInstance().getAlbumNameoforSinger(newSelectedSinger);
    availableAlbums.getItems().setAll(albums);
});
```

- **Bindings**:

you can bind the items of the albums combo box to the selected value of the singer's combo box. Add this listener in your initialize method:

```java
availableAlbums.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    List<Album> albums = Singer.getInstance().getAlbumNameoforSinger(availableSingers.getValue());
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(albums);
}, availableSingers.valueProperty()));
```